# What's best: boil eggs in advance or just before use?

Tags: eggs, storage-lifetime, hard-boiled-eggs

If I want to eat a hard-boiled egg every day of the week, should I boil them and store them (refrigerated) all at once or should I keep raw eggs in the fridge and hard-boil them just before use?

Edit: by best I mean the acceptable trade-off between saving time and energy vs. shelf-life and taste. I mentioned a working week to limit the scope to 5 days, i.e. how much would a hard-boiled egg's taste and texture degrade after 5 days on the fridge?

Comment: Never had trouble with either of the two methods.  Cold eggs are not very tasty though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How long can I store a food in the pantry, refrigerator, or freezer?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21068/how-long-can-i-store-a-food-in-the-pantry-refrigerator-or-freezer)

Comment: If you boil them all at once, you'll certainly save a lot of time (and probably energy as well).

Comment: Your question would be more answerable if you defined what "best" meant.  Do you want to extend shelf life?  Save time? Save energy?  Are cold eggs acceptable for you to consume or would you want to reheat them?  People with different answers to these questions would have different "best"s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By your definition, I would cook them all at one time.  From there you have a couple options.

1. Leave them in the shell and peel when needed.  This keeps out a lot of the air which extends the shelf life to 2 weeks, but can dry them out a little making the texture a little harder.
2. Immediately peel and dry them as best as possible.  Put them in a Zip Lock along with a dry paper towel on the bottom to catch any extra water and condensation.  Remove as much air as possible.   The texture is much better, but your shelf life if approx. 1 week and is a little smellier. (also can put zip lock into a covered container) Lol.  Food stores now sell eggs this way.

Either way you may want to let them sit on the counter long enough to take the chill off, so it's not as hard. For me it doesn't matter, I can eat them any old way.  LOVE EM!